# Jrebel not initializing for embedded tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jrebel, hippocms

I have been unable to get Jrebel to run. I am running a Hippo Java project on mac with the Eclipse plugin. I run the project using `mvn` from a command line (not through the eclipse IDE). I have followed [these](https://www.onehippo.org/library/development/develop-with-jrebel.html) instructions for Hippo and JRebel

I have located the JRebel Eclipse plugin files here:

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins
```

From here I copied the contents of

```
org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_6.5.0.RELEASE/jrebel/
```

which contains 2 files: `jrebel.jar` and `jrebel.plugininfo`

I put these copies into a created directory `~/Tools/jrebel` and pointed the environment variable `REBEL_HOME` to it.

```
export REBEL_HOME=~/Tools/jrebel
```

When I `echo $REBEL_HOME` I get the correct path. When I `cd` to that path and `ls` I get the 2 files.

In my hippo project, from the command line I run

```
mvn clean verify -Djrebel
```

I get build success. Then I run

```
mvn -Pcargo.run -Djrebel
```

This gives the error:

> ```
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ${env.REBEL_HOME}/jrebel.jar 
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Error occurred during initialization of VM 
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] agent library failed to init: instrument
> ```

I have read [here](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/firstaid.html) to specify the path of jrebel.jar to `-javaagent` , but I don't know what this means or how to do it?

Hippo has built in JRebel configurations in the pom.xml. These should be activated with the `-Djrebel` flag. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that in that process REBEL_HOME isn't defined. I don't see anything wrong with what you did here so there may be some peculiarity to your local setup or to MacOS (I'm not a mac user). In any case your environment variable is not being passed to the process.

Everything you said works for me on Linux (Mint).

You can try setting the property in the cargo profile.

Or you could set the variable in your global environment.

Comment: I asked a colleague with a mac to test this and it works for him. Are you perhaps using an alternative shell?